# Skip or delete lines between two patterns

Tags: r, text-mining

I have text-based data that I can read using `readLines`. I would like to use R to eliminate the lines that started with Hello World to !Hello World.

```
abc
adb
exy
Hello World
123
abc
adb
aex
!Hello World
bfd
exy
uyt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standard vector indexing to grab the values that do not fall between the first incidence of `"Hello World"` and the last incidence of `"!Hello World"`:

```
d[!seq_along(d) %in% min(which(d == "Hello World")):max(which(d == "!Hello World"))]
# [1] "abc" "adb" "exp" "bfd" "exy" "uyt"
```

Data:

```
d = c("abc", "adb", "exp", "Hello World", "123", "abc", "adb", "aex", "!Hello World", "bfd", "exy", "uyt")
```